# How to update jupyterlab using conda or pip

Tags: anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-lab

How do you update jupyterlab using conda or pip?

I understand that `conda update jupyter` updates jupyter notebook (I have Anaconda), but I'm not sure this takes care of jupyterlab as well.

Comment: What about us non-Anaconda folks?

Comment: @Abhishek See comment below the answer below for the `pip` command

Answer (score 98, accepted):

`conda update jupyter` will not automatically update jupyterlab. You have to explicitly request an update of jupyterlab:

```
conda update jupyterlab
```

Comment: Alternative: ```pip install --upgrade jupyterlab```

Comment: Do NOT use ```pip install --upgrade jupyterlab``` in a conda environment where jupyterlab was installed with conda, unless you plan to "dead-end" that conda environment (or possibly corrupt it permanently).  For more information, see https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment

Comment: Hi I used this approach, then I found the version I installed is 3.3.2. However in below anaconda website the version is 3.5.0. How do I upgrade it to 3.5.0? Thanks  https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/jupyterlab

Answer (score 35):

You may need to specify conda-forge:

```
conda update -c conda-forge jupyterlab
```

EDIT:
Trying to update to 3.0, `conda update jupyterlab` did not work for me (result of `jupyter lab --version` still was 2.x) and when I tried to specify conda-forge or jupyterlab=3.0 the command hung for too long. I gave up after almost an hour of solving environment. The following worked for me from the Anaconda shell:

```
conda uninstall jupyterlab
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab=3
```

Comment: The same is true for downgrading, e.g. when extensions require a `jupyterlab=2.x`.

Answer (score 24):

I was getting frustrated by trying to update Jupyterlab on Anaconda and failing.
Eventually I realized that this line of code works for me:

```
    conda update --all
```

[image]

Comment: In fact `conda update --all` is a good to refresh and update the entire environment before upgrading a major package like JupyterLab, Jupyter Classic NB, or Spyder so that all the supporting packages are up-to-date before doing your update.  This can help to repair the conda package index caused by packages inadvertently installed using pip into the conda environment.

Answer (score 21):

If you prefer using pip:

```
pip install --upgrade jupyterlab
```

Or if you'd like a specific version:

```
pip install jupyterlab==1.2.4
```

Depending on your rights, you might also need to add a `--user` in there:

```
pip install jupyterlab==1.2.4 --user
```

Comment: Do NOT use pip install --upgrade jupyterlab in a conda environment where jupyterlab was installed with conda, unless you plan to "dead-end" that conda environment (or possibly corrupt it permanently). For more information, see anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment

Answer (score 4):

Experience has taught me, that when you need to upgrade multiple pip packages, the best way is to do it **all at once** (pip will find a good combination of versions and requirements).

So what I did is this.

1. Figure out what jupyterlab uses (your output may differ):

```
$ jupyter --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.9.0
ipykernel        : 6.20.2
ipywidgets       : 8.0.4
jupyter_client   : 8.0.1
jupyter_core     : 5.1.5
jupyter_server   : 2.1.0
jupyterlab       : 3.5.3
nbclient         : 0.7.2
nbconvert        : 7.2.9
nbformat         : 5.7.3
notebook         : 6.5.2
qtconsole        : 5.4.0
traitlets        : 5.8.1
```

2. Put all those in a single line and run `--upgrade`:

```
$ pip install --upgrade IPython ipykernel  ipywidgets jupyter_client jupyter_core jupyter_server jupyterlab nbclient nbconvert nbformat notebook qtconsole traitlets
```

All went smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of back-and-forth with the above methods with conda, none of which worked for me to upgrade nodejs to > v14.x - below is the solution that worked for me, thanks to the link below:

1. conda search nodejs # Search nodejs version under conda.
2. conda install nodejs=14.7.0 -c conda-forge

https://www.programmersought.com/article/39027053707/