# JupyterLab not updates in Anaconda Navigator GUI

Tags: anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-lab, anaconda3

**Goal**

- Updating Jupiter Lab to it's newest/2.1.5/2.xyz version and have that updated version in my Anaconda Navigator GUI

**Setup**

- macOS 10.12
- Anaconda Navigator 1.9.12 (Updated to in the 1st step)

**Tried Solutions**

- Updated Anaconda successfully to current most up to date version of 1.9.12
- Used Anaconda Navigator's GUI Settings gear/Update -> loads for a long time than loading bar disappears than nothing happens, even if I restart Anaconda Navigator
- Used Anaconda Navigator's GUI Settings gear/Update to specific version -> loads for a long time than loading bar disappears than nothing happens, even if I restart Anaconda Navigator
- `conda update jupyterlab` successful installation but in the Anaconda Navigator GUI nothing has changed -> I still have version 0.34 https://stackoverflow.com/a/55792531/10270590
- `conda update -c conda-forge jupyterlab` successful installation but in the Anaconda Navigator GUI nothing has changed -> I still have version 0.34 https://stackoverflow.com/a/58209396/10270590
- `jupyter --version`

  - OUT: `4.4.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I have deleted all files of my Anaconda Navigator https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-anaconda-on-a-mac
2. Done a fresh install https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual -> Anaconda Installers/MacOS/Python 3.7/64-Bit Graphical Installer (442 MB)
3. Than if I open up the fresh install of Anaconda Navigator/ Jupyter Lab/ settings gear/install specific version/ the highest version is offered is 1.2.6 what is also installed with the fresh install.
4. So my guess is that for my system this is the highest version available