# Jupyter Notebook and lab is ruined in python 3.10

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, python-3.10

Jupyter Notebook seems to have lost many features when using it with Python 3.10

1. Cant download a notebook as a .py script. This functionality is gone
2. keyboard shortcuts have become weird. esc shift v doesn't work (only esc v works) etc..
3. Creating a new file/notebook from an open notebook creates the new file in the root directory of Jupyter Notebook, where it was started. This was defaulted to the current notebook directory in the previous Python versions.

What am I missing? Have they not released a newer version of Python 3.10 or have I installed it wrong?

I tried with `pip install jupyter` and `pip install jupyterlab` and even with conda-forge.
Nothing seems to work

Comment: Have you checked the extensions installed for the new Python version? See https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/extensions.html#id10. The download button can be disabled, see https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuring/plugins.html. And, you seeem to be able to customize keyboard shortcuts, see https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Custom%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.html. You could also try to upgrade the Notebook, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55772171/how-to-update-jupyterlab-using-conda-or-pip

Comment: I didnt change anything from default. But looks like notebook 7 version is messed up.

Comment: Your title is not reflective of the actual issue. As you start to touch on in your last comment, it isn't the Python version that is causing the change. It is Jupyter 7+ of the Jupyter Notebook, i.e., the document centric offering by the Jupyter community. See [my answer to 'New Jupyter Notebook Interface'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004). So when you realized that, why not fix the title?

Comment: Yeah looks that way. @Wayne let me checkout nbclassic properly and update it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Wayne I can confirm, nbclassic approach doesnt work. Tried this https://github.com/jupyter/nbclassic

Comment: I commented below that I'm not sure you can confirm much. NbClassic should look and behave like version 6.4 for now.

Answer (score 1):

https://pypi.org/project/notebook/6.4.13/

Just switch to this notebook version.
Uninstall existing ones first (it was notebook7 and jupyterlab 4)

```
pip uninstall jupyterlab
pip uninstall notebook
```

And then reinstall 6.4.13... Solved it. Happy now again.

```
pip install notebook==6.4.13
```

Comment: You **and others encountering related issues like yours** may be able to use NbClassic instead of the much older version you have chosen?  See the second half of [my answer to 'New Jupyter Notebook Interface'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004) discussing NbClassic. NbClassic is the current way to keep using the older version of the notebook.

Comment: Thanks for posting how you solved the issue!

Comment: nbclassic doesnt work @Wayne, I still get the same old pathetic UI after I tried steps from their github https://github.com/jupyter/nbclassic

Comment: I'm not sure that you can say it doesn't work though. It sounds like you failed to install it. Does running the 'About' in Jupyter doesn't indicate you are using it? You should see much the same as version 6.4 if you are actually using NbClassic. I'm really only suggesting NbClassic because you don't want to hang back on 6.4 forever because it won't be updated as NbClassic will going forward. Right now there isn't much difference, however, that is likely to change in the coming month and years and NbClassic is more likely to continue to work with everything whereas 6.4 isn't.